# Is 'Bring forth' archaic?

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm not a native speaker and this is what it feels like to me, probably because of the 'th' ending.

What would be a good modern alternative?

Comment: It might be a little old-fashioned, but I wouldn't call it archaic. Could you give us an example sentence where you would use "bring forth"?

Comment: Please look words up in a dictionary before posting. 3 seconds of googling shows it marked "archaic." Word requests must be accompanied by a sample sentence.

Comment: By the way, I removed the "Old English" tag. This is English, and it is old, but it's not [Old English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English).

Comment: Where did you see it? It is  used in written English, rarely in spoken English.

Comment: It is fairly common in current spoken English.  At least among those with whom I regularly converse.

Comment: Certainly "forth" is a holdover from an older version of the language and is mostly found only in set phrases, but there's enough of those set phrases around that it's not that unusual a word.  You can set forth or go forth, you can come forth, bring forth, or sally forth if you're feeling a little medieval, and most of all you can go back and forth.  In most cases except that last one, it does sound a little elevated or literary, but it's not so far out of normal use that it's archaic.

Comment: @Chenmunka Well, elites do have their own speech patterns and usages.

Answer (score 3):

Contemporary usage of a formal term

The Economist

> A megacity is an urban area with more than 10m inhabitants. Today the world has 34 and the UN predicts that by 2035 the number will rise
> to 48. Although cities can improve livelihoods and create opportunity,
> uncontrolled urban sprawl can **bring forth** myriad problems.

bring forth = give rise to

[How to Manage a Megacity](https://www.economist.com/films/2021/11/23/how-to-manage-a-megacity)

Time Magazine

> Attacks on free and fair elections **bring forth** the reminder that
> even in the most advanced democracy, necessary work must be done to
> shore up institutions such as electoral bodies, the judiciary, and
> even the media.

bring forth = educe

[Elections](https://time.com/6551743/2024-elections-democracy-trump-putin/)